# Не получается импортировать пакет

Tags: java, eclipse

Пытаюсь импортировать, но ничего не получается, Eclipse не знает, что делать и не распознаёт это. Брал информацию [отсюда](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils;
```

Comment: Если вы не используете билдеры(maven, gradle), то вам необходимо скачать нужные jar файлы и вручную добавить их в classpath приложения.

Comment: Можете оформить как ответ и зачту его, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в вашем проекте используется какая-то система сборки проектов([maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164893/how-do-i-add-a-maven-dependency-in-eclipse), [gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171471/eclipse-not-recognizing-gradle-dependencies/44492729)), то вам достаточно будет в их конфигурационных файлах указать необходимые зависимости, после чего система сборки сама скачает все необходимое.

Если же у вас таких систем нет, вы можете скачать jar файл с нужной библиотекой и вручную положить его в classpath вашего приложения([как-то так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463354/how-to-put-a-jar-in-classpath-in-eclipse))

UPD
Отвечая на вопрос про поиск зависимостей:

Обычно паттерн такой: у вас есть импорт, например `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils`

Тут видно, что за автор у пакета(org.apache), проект(commons.lang3). По ним можно уже определить где искать.

Вводите запрос в гугл, и ищите ссылку на github проекта(и там в readme ссылку на мавен репозиторий) или сразу на https://mvnrepository.com/. Там выбираете нужную версию, и попадаете на страницу с выбором заивисимостей для разных систем сборки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете пояснить как понять, что необходимо именно эту библиотеку подключить через maven или gradle?

Comment: @Blacit дополнил ответ, чтобы добавить изображение